# Need to showing screen that show both CLLocation pins

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, core-location

I have mapView that suppose to contain both user location pin and object pin. What i want, is show screen that contain both pins, no matter how large distance is between them (it suppose to be not too much). For some reason i can't show user location, screen moves to some point in the ocean. There is my code and attempts to get it:

```
-(MKCoordinateRegion)regionForAnnotations:(NSArray*)annotations{


    MKCoordinateRegion region;

    if ([annotations count] ==0){
        region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate, 1000, 1000);
    }   else if ([annotations count] ==1 ){
        id <MKAnnotation> annotation = [annotations lastObject];
        region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(annotation.coordinate, 1000, 1000);
    }   else {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D topLeftCord;
        topLeftCord.latitude = -90;
        topLeftCord.longitude = 180;

        CLLocationCoordinate2D bottomRightCord;
        bottomRightCord.latitude = 90;
        bottomRightCord.longitude = -180;

        for (id <MKAnnotation> annotation in annotations){
            topLeftCord.latitude = fmax(topLeftCord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude);
            topLeftCord.longitude = fmin(topLeftCord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude);

            bottomRightCord.latitude = fmin(bottomRightCord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude);
            bottomRightCord.longitude = fmax(bottomRightCord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude);


        }

        const double extraSpace = 1.1;
        region.center.longitude = topLeftCord.longitude - (topLeftCord.longitude - bottomRightCord.longitude)/2.0;
        region.center.latitude = topLeftCord.latitude - (topLeftCord.latitude - bottomRightCord.latitude)/2.0;

        region.span.latitudeDelta = fabs(topLeftCord.latitude - bottomRightCord.latitude)*extraSpace;
        region.span.longitudeDelta = fabs(topLeftCord.longitude - bottomRightCord.longitude)*extraSpace;


    }

    return [self.mapView regionThatFits:region];

}

-(MKAnnotationView*)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation{

    //2
    static NSString *identifier = @"Location";
    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView*)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (annotationView == nil){
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }

    //3
    annotationView.enabled = YES;
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annotationView.animatesDrop = YES;
    annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;

    //4
    UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(getRoute:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

    return annotationView;
};


-(void)setEntityCoordiate{

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = [self.latitudeString doubleValue];
    location.longitude = [self.longitudeString doubleValue];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D user;
    user.latitude = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    user.latitude = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude;

    CLLocation *userLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:user.latitude longitude:user.longitude ];
    CLLocation *entityLocation = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:location.latitude longitude:location.longitude];

    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = 100;
    span.longitudeDelta = 100;

    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location, 400, 400);

    [self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];

    MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    annotation.coordinate = location;
    annotation.title = _titleForEntity;

    [_locations addObject:userLocation];
    [_locations addObject:entityLocation];
    [_mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
}

-(void)getRoute:(UIButton*)button{

    MKCoordinateRegion region = [self regionForAnnotations:_locations];
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setEntityCoordiate];


}
```

There is might be "too much" code, but i can't figure out where i made mistake i paste it all. I think  i might have problem with array containing location objects.

How to finally make screen with that two locations? Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you running on a real device? What are the coordinates for your use relocation? probably 0,0 which is just off west of africa...?

Comment: I tried both real iPhone and simulator. It point to bottom ocean..

Comment: Your main issue (most likely) is that you're trying to read `self.mapView.userLocation` _before_ it has been determined (assuming showsUserLocation is YES in the first place) so the coordinates get saved as 0,0 (Atlantic Ocean).  `setEntityCoordiate` is called in `viewDidLoad` at which point the map probably hasn't set the user location yet.  Not your problem but also note in `setEntityCoordiate`, you are setting `user.latitude` twice (instead of setting `user.longitude` in the 2nd line).

Comment: Oh thanks, that might be the issue, What you suggest, how to call it? in viewDidAppear maybe or throughout other function?

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban, Generally the didUpdateUserLocation delegate method is where you can be sure map view has a location.  However, in your case, you _don't need to store the user location from the beginning in the first place_.  Since you only need to show the region when user taps the callout button, create the "array of locations" in getRoute and _only add mapView.userLocation to the array if `mapView.userLocation.location != nil`_.

Comment: The answer by @Harri will work if you put it in getRoute and replace `annotations` with `mapView.annotations`.  Of course, if the map view still hasn't figured out the user location when that code is called, it will show your annotation only.

Comment: Yes it correct, so that is why i get nil when trying to obtain user coords? Not convenient that i forced to use both Core Location and Map kit framework in single class.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "forced to use both" (_didUpdateUserLocation_ is a MKMapView delegate method -- the CLLocationManager delegate method is _didUpdateToLocation_).  You're not using both here and the same issue would apply to CLLocationManager (which the MKMapView uses itself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating an area `flyTo` that will "contain" your given annotations:

```
MKMapRect flyTo = MKMapRectNull;

for (id <MKAnnotation> annotation in annotations) {
    MKMapPoint annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate);
    MKMapRect pointRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 0, 0);
    if (MKMapRectIsNull(flyTo)) {
        flyTo = pointRect;
    } else {
        flyTo = MKMapRectUnion(flyTo, pointRect);
    }
}

mapview.visibleMapRect = flyTo;
```